# select value of first td while looping through tr in a table - jquery

Tags: jquery

Good day to all,

I have a table with rows and values like below

```
<tr id="value_12">
    <td>firstanme_1</td>
    <td>lastname_1</td>
</tr>
<tr id="value_14">
    <td>firstanme_2</td>
    <td>lastname_2</td>
</tr>
```

and the jquery i am using is (which is abviously wrong).

```
$('#table_id tr').each(function() {
    serializedData += '&' + $(this).attr('id') + '=' + $(this).attr('id')+'_'+$(:first_child).text();
});
```

I am looking to extract only the first  i.e firstname of each tr along with the tr attributes as last part of the serialisedData string(the last value, after the delimiter '_' ).

i may be something like $(this).firstchild().text()  .. but it doesn't seem to work.
can someone please help with the correct way to get the first child in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this

```
$(:first_child).text();
```

With

```
$(this).find("td:first").text();
```

Or Alternately

```
$(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
```

This will fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of the selector `:first_child` is wrong, you can achieve that by using the function `children()` to get the childern of the tr and ':first' as a selector to get only the first one like this:

```
$('#table_id tr').each(function() {
    serializedData += '&' + $(this).attr('id') + '=' + $(this).attr('id')+'_'+$(this).children(":first").text();
            });
```

see jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2t5J2/1/

Answer (score 0):

to get the first child of the tr you could do

```
$('#table_id tr').each(function() {
    var firstName = $("td", tr)[0].val();
    var id = $(tr).attr('id').split("_")[1];
})
```

This should give you the name and the id.

Comment: Your `[0]` is incorrect - it extracts the raw DOM element.  There's also no variable called `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `each` method to collect the data, then construct the query string using jQuery `$.param` function. The benefit is that it will be properly encoded for you:

```
var params = {};
$('table tr[id^="value_"]').each(function() {
    params[this.id] = $(this).find('td:first').text();
});
alert( $.param(params) );  // alerts: value_12=firstanme_1&value_14=firstanme_2
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EwSsu/

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this).children(":first").text() for getting the first child's text.

```
serialData+='&' + $(this).attr('id') + '=' + $(this).attr('id')+'_'+$(this).children(":first").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the value of the first TD :

```
$(this).find("td:first-child").text();
```